# Multiple conditionals in Julia DataFrame

Tags: dataframe, julia, control-flow, dataframes.jl

I have a DataFrame with 3 columns, named :x :y and :z which are Float64 type. :x and "y are iid uniform on (0,1) and z is the sum of x and y.
I want to a simple task. If x and y are both greater than 0.5 I want to print z and replace its value to 1.0.
For some reason the following code is running but not working

```
if df.x .> 0.5 && df.y .> 0.5
  println(df.z)
  replace!(df, :z) .= 1.0
end
```

Would appreciate any help on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is working on whole columns, and you want the code to work on rows. The simplest way to do it is (there are faster ways to do it, but the one I show you is simplest):

```
julia> using DataFrames

julia> df = DataFrame(rand(10, 2), [:x, :y]);

julia> df.z = df.x + df.y;
julia> df = DataFrame(rand(10, 2), [:x, :y]);

julia> df.z = df.x + df.y;

julia> df
10×3 DataFrame
 Row │ x           y         z
     │ Float64     Float64   Float64
─────┼────────────────────────────────
   1 │ 0.00461518  0.767149  0.771764
   2 │ 0.670752    0.891172  1.56192
   3 │ 0.531777    0.78527   1.31705
   4 │ 0.0666402   0.265558  0.332198
   5 │ 0.700547    0.25959   0.960137
   6 │ 0.764978    0.84093   1.60591
   7 │ 0.720063    0.795599  1.51566
   8 │ 0.524065    0.260897  0.784962
   9 │ 0.577509    0.62598   1.20349
  10 │ 0.363896    0.266637  0.630533

julia> for row in eachrow(df)
           if row.x > 0.5 && row.y > 0.5
               println(row.z)
               row.z = 1.0
           end
       end
1.5619237447442418
1.3170464579861205
1.6059082278386194
1.515661749106264
1.2034891678047939

julia> df
10×3 DataFrame
 Row │ x           y         z
     │ Float64     Float64   Float64
─────┼────────────────────────────────
   1 │ 0.00461518  0.767149  0.771764
   2 │ 0.670752    0.891172  1.0
   3 │ 0.531777    0.78527   1.0
   4 │ 0.0666402   0.265558  0.332198
   5 │ 0.700547    0.25959   0.960137
   6 │ 0.764978    0.84093   1.0
   7 │ 0.720063    0.795599  1.0
   8 │ 0.524065    0.260897  0.784962
   9 │ 0.577509    0.62598   1.0
  10 │ 0.363896    0.266637  0.630533
```

#### Edit

Assuming you do not need to print here is a benchmark of several options:

```
julia> df = DataFrame(rand(10^7, 2), [:x, :y]);

julia> df.z = df.x + df.y;

julia> @time for row in eachrow(df) # slowest
           if row.x > 0.5 && row.y > 0.5
               row.z = 1.0
           end
       end
  3.469350 seconds (90.00 M allocations: 2.533 GiB, 10.07% gc time)

julia> @time df.z[df.x .> 0.5 .&& df.y .> 0.5] .= 1.0; # fast and simple
  0.026041 seconds (15 allocations: 20.270 MiB)

julia> function update_condition!(x, y, z)
           @inbounds for i in eachindex(x, y, z)
               if x[i] > 0.5 && y[i] > 0.5
                   z[i] = 1.0
               end
           end
           return nothing
       end
update_condition! (generic function with 1 method)

julia> update_condition!(df.x, df.y, df.z); # compilation

julia> @time update_condition!(df.x, df.y, df.z); # faster but more complex
  0.011243 seconds (3 allocations: 96 bytes)
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Bogumil !! Can you point towards the faster method? My data frame is missive and this was just a simple example to understand the use of conditionals? Thanks!

Comment: I can point you to a faster method, but the most expensive operation in your code is printing - any other operations will be much faster anyway. I will add you information how to do it faster assuming you do not want to print anything.

Answer (score 3):

The following `ifelse` is 60X faster than a loop for 500k rows dataframe.

```
using DataFrames
x = rand(500_000)
y = rand(500_000)
z = x + y
df = DataFrame(x = x, y = y, z = z)

df.z .= ifelse.((df.x .> 0.5) .&& (df.y .> 0.5), 1.0, df.z)
```

Comment: yes, but it does not print `z` when it is updated and this was the original requirement of OP. In relation to my proposed solutions it is faster than the `Bool` mask solution but slower than the custom function solution.

Comment: Printing is not necessary in the eventual output. But I had tried this and I see the reason why it failed is because I did not broadcast the &&. Thanks!!